# Logstash configuration variable expansion

Tags: logstash, filebeat

I have a strange problem with a logstash filter, that was working up until yesterday.

This is my .conf file:

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}

filter {
  if "access.log" in [source] {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{GREEDYDATA:messagebefore}\[%{HTTPDATE:real_date}\]\ %{GREEDYDATA:messageafter}" }
    }

    mutate {
      replace => { "[message]" => "%{messagebefore} %{messageafter}" }
      remove_field => [ "messagebefore" ]
      remove_field => [ "messageafter" ]
    }

    date {
      match => [ "real_date", "dd/MMM/YYYY:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
    }
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
  }
}
```

The issue is that in the output, the derived variables %messagebefore and %message after are coming through as literal text, rather than the content.

Example:

```
source:/var/log/nginx/access.log message:%{messagebefore} %{messageafter}...
```

The strange thing is that this was working fine before yesterday afternoon.  I also appreciate that this is probably not the best way to process nginx logs, but I'm using this one as an example only as it's affecting all of my other configuration files as well.

My environment:

ELK stack running as a docker container on Centos 7 derived from docker.io/sebp/elk.

Filebeat running on Centos 7 client.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this myself, and posting here in case anyone gets the same issue.

When building the docker container, I inadvertently left behind another .conf file that also contained reference to access.log.  The two .conf files were clashing as logstash was processing both.  I deleted the erroneous file and it has all started working.